# How to get name of an option value when validation returns false in laravel 5

Tags: javascript, php, forms, laravel, laravel-blade

In a form I have multiple options

```
<div class="form-group">
                    <label>Seasons</label>
                    <select class="form-control" name="year_code" required>
                        <option value="{{ Input::old ('year_code') }}"
                                selected>{{ Input::old ('year_code') }}</option>
                        <div class="divider"></div>
                        <option value="16">2016-2017</option>
                        <option value="17">2017-2018</option>
                        <option value="18">2018-2019</option>
                        <option value="20">2020-2021</option>

                    </select>
                </div>
```

If validation fails because of wrong values (php side validation) 
my form returns back with old inputs, lets say season 2016-2017 is selected 
if my form fails returning value will be 16 and it'll be shown. 
I can do multiple if statements like

```
@if(\Input::get(year_code) == 16) 
show 2016-2017
@elseif (\Input::get(year_code) == 17)
show 2017-2018
... 
@endif
```

but I am looking for more efficient way to get names of a values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of hardcoding, keep them in a multidimensional array so you can do manipulations easier.

```
$arr = [
   ["value" => 16, "text" => "2016-2017"],
   ["value" => 17, "text" => "2017-2018"],
   ["value" => 18, "text" => "2018-2019"]
   ...
];
```

Pass that data to your views with a ViewComposer.

```
@foreach($arr as $entry)
   @if((int) Input::old('year_code') === $entry['value'])
       <option value="{{ $entry['value'] }}" selected>{{ $entry['text'] }}</option>
   @else
       <option value="{{ $entry['value'] }}">{{ $entry['text'] }}</option>
   @endif
@endforeach
```

Also, seems like values can be automatically generated. I would personally create a date iterator which looks like this. (pseudo)

```
public function getYears(int $diff): array {
    $start    = Date::today()->startOfYear();
    $end      = Date::today()->addYears($diff)->startOfYear();
    $response = [];

    $start->diffInYears($end, function ($year) use (&response) {
        $response[] = sprintf("%s - %s", $year->format("Y"), $year->addYear()->format("Y"));
    });

    return $response;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="form-group">
<label>Seasons</label>
<select class="form-control" name="year_code" required>
    <option value="16" {{\Input::get(year_code)==16?'selected':''}}>2016-2017</option>
    <option value="17" {{\Input::get(year_code)==17?'selected':''}}>2017-2018</option>
    <option value="18" {{\Input::get(year_code)==18?'selected':''}}>2018-2019</option>
    <option value="20" {{\Input::get(year_code)==20?'selected':''}}>2020-2021</option>

 </select>
 </div>
```

Comment: there is no difference between ternary and if statement in this situation I think I look for an efficent way maybe somehow get names with javascript depending on values.